# product of barycentric coordinates over a simplex

Tags: integration, simplex

Show that:

$$\int_K \eta_0^{\alpha_0}(x)\cdots\eta_n(x)^{\alpha_n}dx=\frac{{\alpha_0}!\cdots{\alpha_n}!n!|K|}{(\alpha_0+\cdots+\alpha_n+n)!}$$

where $\eta_i$ barycentric coordinates and $K$ is a $n$-dim simplex.

I know that

$$\int_\tilde K \eta_0^{\alpha_0}(x)\cdots\eta_n(x)^{\alpha_n}dx=\frac{{\alpha_0}!\cdots{\alpha_n}!}{(\alpha_0+\cdots+\alpha_n+n)!}$$

where $\tilde K$ is the standard simplex. How do I get the factor $n!|K|$ from the transformation?

edit: If T is the trafo then $|det T|=n!|K|$

Comment: You shouldn't have the variable $x$ appearing to the right of "$=$" if the thing to its left is a definite integral with respect to $x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I haven't yet succeeded in understanding the question.  I wonder if what you actually want to prove is that the integral of $\eta_0^{\alpha_0-1}\cdots\eta_n^{\alpha_n-1}$ over the simplex is $\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha_0)\cdots\Gamma(\alpha_n)}{\Gamma(\alpha_0+\cdots+\alpha_n)}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If $\eta_0(x),\ldots,\eta_n(x)$ are supposed to be the barycentric coordinates of a point $x$ in the simplex, then not only should the variable $x$ not appear on the right side, but neither should those functions of it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: i think the factor $|K|$ stems from the transformation of the to standard simplex It's just the jacobian determinant of this trafo. About the $n!$ i'm not sure

Comment: Sorry there were some mistakes... what I did is to determine the integral over the standard simplex (this was a hint) to determine the integral over the regular simplex.

Comment: $n!|K| = \frac{|K|}{|\tilde{K}|}$ is the Jacobian determinant.

Comment: By "the standard simplex", I would guess you mean the convex hull of the points $(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}, 1,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0})$ where the $1$ is in the $k$th position, for $k=0,\ldots,n$.  You also refer to "the $n$-dim simplex".  Your phrasing makes it appear that you consider these two different simplices.  I know of just one so far.  What "transformation" are you referring to?  Also, you're still not clear about the matters I've mentioned in comments above.

Comment: OK, it appears that now you've cleaned up the right sides of the two equalities.  I await clarification of the transformation.

Comment: I mean the transformation from the standard simplex to the regular one. I hope my notes help you to clarify your question.

Comment: @achillehui that solves it. I calculated $|\tilde K|$ and is it $\frac{1}{n!}$. Thanks!